# What is the tension in the spring when its overall length is 70 mm?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

A spring obeying Hooke’s Law has an upstretched length of 50 mm and a spring constant of
400 N m-1. What is the tension in the spring when its overall length is 70 mm?
My solution:
400/50*70=560NM is my answer correct? I don't have the solution :( please help

Comment: Upstretched? As opposed to downstretched? But, no, your answer is not correct.

Comment: Do you mean "unstretched" length?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

According to Hooke's Law, the spring force is directly proportional to the *displacement of the spring from its equilibrium position* with the proportionality constant being given by the *stiffness or spring constant.* You need to calculate the *displacement from equilibrium* given *two* lengths.